# Appending to a file is not working

Tags: java, io

I Couldn't write continuously to the file. I want to have a function that has to append to the file. But, I couldn't get what I need. Can anybody help me if there is any mistake with the code written.

```
void writeLog(String s)
{
  try
  {
    String filename= "D:\\Gardening\\Logs.txt";
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true); //the true will append the new data
    fw.write(s+"\n");//appends the string to the file
    fw.close();
  }
  catch(IOException ioe)
  {
    System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Guys, I found the problem in the constructor of the class, The full code is here

```
Class Log
{
   Log()
   {
      try{
      FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("path of file");
      }
      catch(Exception a)
      {
         System.err.println(a);
      }
   }
   void writeLog(String s)
   {
     try
     {
String filename= "D:\\Gardening\\Logs.txt";
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true); //the true will append the new data
fw.write(s+"\n");//appends the string to the file
fw.close();
 }
 catch(IOException ioe)
 {
   System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
 }
}
```

As it was being called in the constructor again and again It was happening like that.

Comment: this should append s + \n to Logs.txt, what sort of errors do you get?

Comment: i tried your code, and it works perfectly,please explain more?

Comment: "But, I couldn't get what I need." Please provide a real description of the problems / errors that you are getting.

Comment: It is not appending to the file. I don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested your code and it's working fine. Can you post your full code ? Also how are you calling the writeLog method.

```
public class Test {
    void writeLog(String s) {
        try {
            String filename = "C:\\Temp\\Logs.txt";
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true);
            fw.write(s + "\n");
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            t1.writeLog("Hello");
        }

    }
}
```

This code creates a Logs.txt with the following content -

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create your FileWriter outside of the method where you call it and give it to your method as a second parameter.(If you will append strings to your file in whole project, you can create your FileWriter as singleton) There is no need to recreate FileWriter again and again.

By the way you should close FileWriter in finally block. Because in your code if an exception occured before close operation FileWriter cannot be closed. My code advice is like below:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileWriter fw = null;
            try {

             fw = new FileWriter(filename,true);
             writeLog("Your String", fw);

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
            }
             finally
          {
               try {
                if(fw != null)
                fw.close();
            }  catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }


    }

    static void writeLog(String s , FileWriter fw)
        {
          try
          {
            fw.write(s+"\n"); 
          }
          catch(IOException ioe)
          {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
          }

        }
```